# AttributeError: module 'google._upb._message' has no attribute 'Message'

Tags: protocol-buffers

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/news/2022-05-06#python-updates

Google has made some changes in Python language support in Protocol Buffers so one bug that occurs is the title of this question, the solution was just to downgrade to an earlier version

Answer (score 3):

Had this error, solution was to downgrade protobuf
just added protobuf==3.20.1 to requirements.txt